# Spring security ajax login use http redirect instead of https

Tags: apache, spring-mvc, ssl, spring-security, https

I just migrate my webapp to HTTPS and everything works fine except ajax login.(although non ajax login works)

When I try to log in, I get the following error message :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.foo.bar/paris' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.foo.bar/security/ajax-success'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

and in the network tab I get

```
https://www.foo.bar/security/ajax-login     status - > canceled
http://www.foo.bar/security/ajax-success    status -> blocked(mixed-content)
```

I use apache2 and tomcat with ProxyPass
here is my default-ssl config :

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin contact@foo.bar
    ServerName www.foo.bar
    ErrorLog /home/apache_logs/error_website.log
    CustomLog /home/apache_logs/access_website.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/sslcerts/certs/www.foo.bar.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/sslcerts/private/foo.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/sslcerts/certs/foo.pem
    SSLVerifyClient None
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://0.0.0.0:8080/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.foo.bar
    ServerAlias foo.bar
    Redirect "/" "https://www.foo.bar/"
</VirtualHost>
```

I use Spring security in this java web app, here is my config file :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/security/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/security/ajax-login")
                .loginPage("/security/ajax-login-page")
                .failureUrl("/ajax-failure")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/security/ajax-success", true)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("hdfyer")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/app/logout"));
    }
}

@Configuration
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**")
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/account").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessCallback())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("jforumUserInfo")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    }

    @Bean(name = "myAuthenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
}
```

I tried to add requiresChannel or portMapper without success (it sometimes fail with a too many redirect error though...).

I fail too see what is wrong with these configuration.
How can I make spring security redirects ajax login success on https instead of http ?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions is quite simple:

Add below line of code to your configure method

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.requiresChannel().antMatchers("/login**,/user**").requiresSecure();
}
```

Note:/login**,/logout** should be mentioned as part of proxy pass in your apache2 configuration
add to antMatcher - whichever request is redirecting from https to http.

One more thing to be added in you apache2 configuration
 `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https`

and 
In your spring-boot application.properties (if you have)
add below properties

**server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=x-forwarded-for

server.tomcat.protocol_header=x-forwarded-proto**